# Trace all Excel Functions called

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet which has many functions split across many modules and classes. I would like to know which functions / subroutines are actually being used and which I can actually eliminate. Is there any way I can produce some sort of log which would tell me this ? (I was told MZ tools may be able to provide this but was unable to find it). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is an answer, but have you looked at
http://www.mztools.com/index.aspx

Make sure you download the right version, though.

By the way, I've been using MZtools (free) for a while, and I can guarantee that it's a very good piece of software for that price.

Comment: You need the admin rights to install it though and it is a pain to get in the corp world. Which is a shame.